# Изменение элемента массива char

Tags: java

Задача - в поступающей строке заменить каждый 10й символ звездочкой `*`.

Удаляемые символы конкатенировать в строку ответа.
Например, при содержимом файла:

```
0123456789012345678A012345678B01
```

новое содержимое должно быть

```
012345678*012345678*012345678*01
```

и метод должен вернуть `9AB`

```java
public String setStars(String filename) {
    char[] newChr = new char[10];
    String newStr = "";
    String ansStr = "";
    int x = 0;
    try {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
        char[] chr = String.valueOf(file).toCharArray();
        for (x = x; x < chr.length - 1; x++) {
            if (x % 10 == 9) {
                ansStr = ansStr + chr[x];
                chr[x] = char("*");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return ansStr;
}
```

**Вопрос:** как присвоить символ элементу массива?

```java
chr[x] = char("*");
```

Comment: Не те кавычки `chr[x]= '*';`

Comment: Оффтоп: x = x можно и не писать

Comment: @Miron тут логичнее `int x = 0` сделать в инициализации цикла, не понятно зачем оно до try делается.

Comment: @Eugene_Venev неправильно понимаете. Я написал, как лучше бы было сделать в данной ситуации. Это скорее мое видение как лучше писать, а как вы сделаете в итоге - дело ваше. Новичок вы или нет - вообще не имеет значения.

Answer (score 0):

1. В Вашем массиве chr лежит строковое представление объекта RandomAccessFile, а не строка из файла. Чтобы корректно прочитать из файла можно использовать FileReader и BufferedReader из пакета java.io

   ```
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
   ```
2. Для конкатенации строк лучше использовать StringBuilder, при конкатенации через += вы каждую итерацию порождаете новую строку.

   ```
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
        ans.append(line.charAt(i));
   ```
3. В вашем цикле for лучше инициализировать переменную внутри цикла, и итерироваться до x < chr.length, при условии x < chr.length - 1 Вы не проверяете последний символ.

   ```
         for (x = 0; x < chr.length; x++) {...}
   ```
4. Чтобы присвоить нужное значение стоит написать

   ```
         chr[x] = '*';
   ```